# Trigger an Event after x seconds, but also cancel it before it executes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing an Web API (which works quite well). What's missing?
Here is sample code of `Get` Action:

```
public IEnumerable<xxxx> Get()
{           
    IEnumerable<xxxx> yyyy = new List<xxxx>();
    //get yyyy from database
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Interval = 5000; //miliseconds
    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start();
    return yyyy;
}
void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //code to be executed when timer elapses...
}
```

So once a request is received, timer will be initialized and will fire `Elapsed` event at interval of 5 seconds. On next subsequent request this continues....

The expected behavior is such that:

1. Initialize Request -1
2. Initialize Timer -1
3. If another request from same client is received within 5 seconds, timer must not fire elapsed event.
4. If no request is received from same client within 5 seconds, timer should elapse and fire the event.

***Also the timer has nothing to do with client(s).***

Here is further business scenario related to this....
I'm developing a Web API that will be consumed by an electronic device when switched on. The device will keep sending it's ON status as long as the power is available. As soon as, user turns off the switch, the request to the server stops.

These status are updated into database whether device is ON or OFF. Now the trickier part was to identify when device turns off (complicated because the server does not know anything if the device stops sending any request). So for each devices there is a separate timer.

Comment: how do you identify clients?

Comment: What code do you want to run inside the `Elapsed`? I think this is an XY problem.

Comment: I really do not need to identify the clients.... My implementation has nothing to do with client. The implementation assumes that, all clients are similar and will be served with same data... though, it is possible to have multiple timers based on other criteria

Comment: @PatrickHofman What code should be inside `Elapsed`? It can be anything... say I'm initializing a variable and that not used anywhere else.

Comment: You have to show us what exactly would go there, because that will influence the approach.

Comment: @PatrickHofman That's really up to me... I'm going to update a variable value in session or in cache... I'm not through this code... I'm doing POC for this approach and I'm checking it possibilities.

Comment: Then don't use a timer. That code runs in another thread where you don't have access to session variables...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115832/discussion-between-hiren-desai-and-patrick-hofman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you @Patrick Hofman to guide me and think out of box...
I implemented a class having static property inside it.

```
public class DeviceContainer
{
    public static List<DevTimer> timers=new List<DevTimer>();
}
public class DevTimer:Timer
{
    public string Identifier {get; set;}
    public bool IsInUse{get; set;}
}
```

and then in above code (in question), I made following changes:

```
public IEnumerable<xxxx> Get(string Id)
{        
    //Check if timer exists in
    if(!DeviceContainer.timers.Any(s=>s.Identifier.Equals(Id)))
    {
         //Create new object of timer, assign identifier =Id, 
         //set interval and initialize it. add it to collection as
         var timer = new DevTimer();
         timer.AutoReset = true;
         timer.Enabled = true;
         timer.Interval = 5000; //miliseconds
         timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
         timer.IsInUse=true;
         timer.Identifier=Id;             
         DeviceContainer.timers.Add(timer);
         timer.Start();
    }
    else
    {
         //Code to stop the existing timer and start it again.
         var _timer=DeviceContainer.timers.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Identifier.Equals(Id)) 
                      as DevTimer;
         _timer.Stop();
         _timer.Start();
    }        

}
void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //code that will turn off the device in DB
}
```

I'm not posting the entire code as that's not the purpose here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this.

Here's the code:

```
IEnumerable<xxxx> yyyy = new List<xxxx>();

Subject<Unit> clientRequestArrived = new Subject<Unit>();

IDisposable subscription =
    clientRequestArrived
        .Select(_ => Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)))
        .Switch()
        .Subscribe(_ =>
        {
            //code to be executed when timer elapses...
            //directly access `yyyy` here
        });
```

All you need to do is call `clientRequestArrived.OnNext(Unit.Default);` every time that a user request comes in and that will be enough for this code to reset the timer.

If you want to stop the timer entirely, just call `subscription.Dispose()`.

Comment: 2 Questions here, Will this code run on main thread blocking my UI or current HttpRequest? and second that, The code above is specifically in context on ASP.NET which is stateless and these is nothing such as Global variable or object. The 'subscription' and 'yyyy' instance won't be accessible in subsequent request. That is  my belief ... I might be wrong as well. But I'll definitely look into **Reactive Framework**

Comment: @HirenDesai - I had figured that you were running some sort of long-running service to have your timer function properly. And this code will be automatically pushed to a separate thread. There are ways in Rx to easily marshall back to the UI if need be.